# SnapsToDevicePixels for every control?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I somehow apply SnapsToDevicePixels for every control? I don't know what to do. I did some experimenting with styles that apply to all kinds of controls, but that didn't work for me.

Are there any ways of doing this?

Comment: Would be awesome to get that confirmed if possible.

Comment: As Cicada suggests, this property is inherited down your visual tree.  However, it will typically make text and graphical elements render horribly, as it breaks anti-aliasing/cleartype somewhat in favour of pixel-aligned positioning.  You might not like the effect of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you apply `SnapsToDevicePixels` to your root element, all children will inherit it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx):

> **Remarks** You can set this property to true on your root element to enable pixel snap rendering throughout the UI.

Answer (score 1):

if you set "SnapsToDevicePixels=True", by default this value is set to all child controls.

Check Value Precedence on this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Thanks
Jeetendra